# Why can't I clone from my private repository?

Tags: windows, git

I have a `git` repository on my primary development machine (Linux) which I regularly `git push` to a remote SSH server for backup purposes. I now want to do some work on that repository from a Windows machine. So, I installed Git for Windows, set up SSH keys, etc.

From Git Bash, I can `ssh` into my server without issue. However, this fails:

```
$ git clone --config=core.symlinks=true -- user@host:/private/site.git destination
Cloning into 'destination'...
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa':
fatal: '/private/site.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I know for certain that I supplied the correct username, hostname, and path, as I've double- and triple-checked it. I've checked the permissions on `/private/site.git` and they're OK: My user account has read-write access. I routinely push to the remote repository from the other machine without issue, so obviously it's configured correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that `/private/site.git` is interpreted starting from the *home directory* of `user@host`, not from the root directory of `host`. This is because the URL is really `ssh://user@host/private/site.git`. It does not matter how many slashes you squeeze in: `ssh://user@host/////////private/site.git` is still `private/site.git`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, despite checking multiple times, I was supplying the incorrect host path. I didn't notice it until I logged into the host to check something else. D'oh.

Comment: Good catch on the hostname. +1

Answer (score 0):

First, for testing, define a private key *without* passphrase.

Then make sure your public key is published to `host@~user/.ssh/authorized_keys` (as one line, not multiple line: the copy can be tricky)

Finally, check if your key is indeed use with:

```
cmd /v /c "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -v&& git clone user@host:/private/site.git destination"
```